# Scrreprt - Show Pagenumbers in TOC-Pages when using scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, koma-script, page-numbering, scrreprt

I'm writing a report with class `scrreprt` and wanted to use `scrlayer-scrpage` for the headlines of each page.

However today I noticed, that the pagenumbering on all toc- and listoff-pages disappeared. How can I get them back, preferably in the footline?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum, scrlayer-scrpage}

\clearpairofpagestyles{}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{pagination}{}

\ohead{Seite~\pagemark}
\ihead{Some Author}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\clearpairofpagestyle` you have removed all elements from both, the headings and the plain style of `scrheadings`. So you either should replace `\clearpairofpagestyle` by `\clearmainofpairofpagestyles` to only clean the headings style if `scrheadings` or re-add the page number to the plain style also, e.g., using `\ohead*` instead of `\ohead`. See also the meaning of the optional argument of `\cfoot` etc. if you really want the page number at the foot of plain pages.

Comment: Hence my idea to Pose this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, in one comment you asked for a documentation of good typography.

Well, `scrreprt` is already prepared for good typography. No, it is no joke, I realy mean this!

Please have a look on the following code (it is the one you gave in your question with little changings from me. I simply deleted `\clearpairofpagestyles`, `\ohead` and `\ihead`):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum, scrlayer-scrpage}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{pagination}{}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: good typography]

As you can see you got page numbers on all pages, including the starting page of a chapter or the toc (not shown in image). That is supposed to be good typography.

Now we can change this code a little bit, to get the name of the author and "Seite" into the footline, in **all**  footlines:

[image: good typography 2]

**I recommend this layout as good typography! ^^^^^**

In contrast to this see the information from footer in the header, all headers:

[image: bad typography]

caused by this code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum, scrlayer-scrpage}

%\clearpairofpagestyles{} % <===========================================

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{pagination}{}

\ohead*{Seite~\pagemark} % <============================================
\ihead*{Some Author} % <================================================
\ofoot*{} % <========================================== clear outer foot

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Just a remark to the used commands `\ofoot*{}` etc. Command `ofoot` means outer foot, the place alway on the outer place of your pages. The `*` in the command means that not only the usual pages (no chapter start, no TOC, etc.) but also the special pages (starting page of chapter, TOC, etc.)  are set with the given content into outer place of footline. Simular for the other used commands ...

But never ever change the position of a pagemark in your document. **Decide where it has to be and then let the pagenumber stay there**. Do not suddenly write it on another place!